# Магазин на Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пишу магазин для своего сервера Discord. У меня возникла проблема с добавлением роли в магазин. Буду очень благодарен, если вы мне поможете.

```py
@Client.command()
async def shop(ctx, value=None, price=None, role=None):
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Магазин", colour=0x2ecc71)
    emb.insert_field_at(index=0, name=role, value=price)
    if value == None:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
    if value == 'addtostore':
```

Answer (score 1):

```
author = ctx.message.author      
guild = client.get_guild(id='Здесь id сервера')
role = guild.get_role(role_id='Здесь id роли')
await author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]